# Preserving order or array in has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a model CardSet which `has_many :cards, :order => "cards.order"`. When I update `some_card_set.cards = cards_in_a_particular_order`, and then `some_card_set.save`, I want it so `some_card_set.cards` returns the next time with the cards in the same order I entered them in. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Either do it manually, or use one of a ton of `acts_as_ordered` plugins, like [this](https://github.com/pahowes/acts_as_ordered_list) or [this](https://github.com/jhnsntmthy/acts_as_ordered_list) etc.

Comment: Looks like those are both intended for Rails 2.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a table design similar to

```
cards {
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  value VARCHAR(5),
  suite VARCHAR(10)
}

card_sets {
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(30),
}
```

Then I would have a join table something like:

```
card_set_orders {
  card_set_id INT,
  card_id INT,
  order_index INT

}
```

You would have to change your has many to reflect the join syntax. Then you could have an 'on load' function 'order' for the set.  So you'll need:
  1) a new migration
  2) a new activerecord model
  3) ordering method that you can invoke on find, or manually
  4) updated has_many

Comment: I don't need a join table. It is a one-to-many relationship. I can already set up an order field, the issue is having rails automatically manage assignment of order.